# Not allowed to load local resource error in electron - angular v7.0.1

Tags: angular, electron

I'm trying to set up my application with Electron for the first time. The initial steps of adding main.js, changing the index.html, changing the package.json are done. While I try to run the application using the command `npm run electron-build`, I get a screen as below.

[Error-while-running-electron-app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTKL5.png)

I'm not able to run my application. It isn't an error basically, but just lack of information. Any help regarding this will be much appreciated. TIA.

**main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

let win;

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 600, 
    height: 600,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    icon: `file://${__dirname}/dist/assets/logo.png`
  })


  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/index.html`)

  win.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Event when the window is closed.
  win.on('closed', function () {
    win = null
  })
}

// Create window on electron intialization
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {

  // On macOS specific close process
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  // macOS specific close process
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

**package.json**

```
 "name": "angular-electron-first-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "electron .",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "electron-build": "ng build --prod && npm run electron ."
  },
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularElectron</title>
  <base href="./">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

</body>
</html>
```

Other details:
Angular v7.1.0
RxJS v6.5.2
NPM v6.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to look for an answer, I tried and came across that the issue lies in the `loadURL` of **main.js**. The below code change resolved the issue for me.

**main.js**

From

```
win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/index.html`)
```

To

```
win.loadURL(`file:///${__dirname}/dist/angular-electron-first-app/index.html`);
```

Here, angular-election-first-app is the project folder that gets created in the dist folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use [loadFile](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winloadfilefilepath-options) with local resources

> win.loadFile(filePath[, options])
>
> ```
> filePath String
>
> options Object (optional)
>     query Object (optional) - Passed to url.format().
>     search String (optional) - Passed to url.format().
>     hash String (optional) - Passed to url.format().
> ```
>
> Returns Promise - the promise will resolve when the page has
>   finished loading (see did-finish-load), and rejects if the page fails
>   to load (see did-fail-load).
>
> Same as webContents.loadFile, filePath should be a path to an HTML
>   file relative to the root of your application. See the webContents
>   docs for more information.

Comment: The `loadURL` was the issue is what I figured out. Updating it solved the issue for me.